# Powershell extract data from really weird JSON file

Tags: json, powershell, select-string

I have a really weird json file and I am trying to extract data from it via powershell.

The issue is that the creator of this file is using json in a way I have never seen before:

(Cities are not in the Array, Continents are not in the array etc)

Shortened JSON File:

```
{
"zscloud.net": {
    "continent : EMEA": {
        "city : Abu Dhabi I": [
            {
                "range": "147.161.174.0/23",
                "vpn": "",
                "gre": "",
                "hostname": "",
                "latitude": "24.453884",
                "longitude": "54.3773438"
            }
        ],
        "city : Amsterdam II": [
            {
                "range": "185.46.212.0/23",
                "vpn": "amsterdam2-vpn.zscloud.net",
                "gre": "185.46.212.36",
                "hostname": "ams2.sme.zscloud.net",
                "latitude": "52",
                "longitude": "5"
            },
            {
                "range": "147.161.228.0/23",
                "vpn": "",
                "gre": "",
                "hostname": "",
                "latitude": "52",
                "longitude": "5"
            },
            {
                "range": "165.225.240.0/23",
                "vpn": "ams2-2-vpn.zscloud.net",
                "gre": "165.225.240.42",
                "hostname": "ams2-2.sme.zscloud.net",
                "latitude": "52",
                "longitude": "5"
            },
            {
                "range": "147.161.172.0/23",
                "vpn": "",
                "gre": "165.225.240.42",
                "hostname": "",
                "latitude": "52",
                "longitude": "5"
            },
            {
                "range": "147.161.230.0/23",
                "vpn": "",
                "gre": "",
                "hostname": "",
                "latitude": "52",
                "longitude": "5"
            },
            {
                "range": "147.161.232.0/23",
                "vpn": "",
                "gre": "",
                "hostname": "",
                "latitude": "52",
                "longitude": "5"
            },
            {
                "range": "147.161.234.0/23",
                "vpn": "",
                "gre": "",
                "hostname": "",
                "latitude": "52",
                "longitude": "5"
            },
            {
                "range": "147.161.224.0/23",
                "vpn": "",
                "gre": "",
                "hostname": "",
                "latitude": "52",
                "longitude": "5"
            },
            {
                "range": "147.161.226.0/23",
                "vpn": "",
                "gre": "",
                "hostname": "",
                "latitude": "52",
                "longitude": "5"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I am trying to get the name of the city + the nested hostname.

My Options:

1. I can either use Convertfrom-JSON and then somehow iterate over several unknown Keys and Properties.
2. Or I can use select-string and basically grep only the matching regex. Then put them into array etc.

Previously, I went with select-string against beautified JSON as it was easier.

Today, I have found out that not only Hostname but  Hostname + City name may be required. Any idea how to extract them from the json?

I am on PS5.

Many Thanks,
Aster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can either use `ConvertFrom-JSON` and then **somehow iterate over several unknown Keys and Properties**.

Let me show you how!

PowerShell allows you to programmatically discover the properties of any object via the `psobject` hidden memberset:

```
PS ~> $someObject = [pscustomobject]@{ A = 123; B = "a string value" }
PS ~> $someObject.psobject.Properties


MemberType      : NoteProperty
IsSettable      : True
IsGettable      : True
Value           : 123
TypeNameOfValue : System.Int32
Name            : A
IsInstance      : True

MemberType      : NoteProperty
IsSettable      : True
IsGettable      : True
Value           : a string value
TypeNameOfValue : System.String
Name            : B
IsInstance      : True
```

Applied to your JSON input, we could do something like this:

```
# The following assumes you've loaded the JSON into a string like below
$json = @'
{
    "zscloud.net": {
        "continent : EMEA": {
            "city : Abu Dhabi I": [
                {
                    "range": "147.161.174.0/23",
                    "vpn": "",
                    "gre": "",
                    "hostname": "",
                    "latitude": "24.453884",
                    "longitude": "54.3773438"
                }
            ],
            "city : Amsterdam II": [
                {
                    "range": "185.46.212.0/23",
                    "vpn": "amsterdam2-vpn.zscloud.net",
                    "gre": "185.46.212.36",
                    "hostname": "ams2.sme.zscloud.net",
                    "latitude": "52",
                    "longitude": "5"
                },
                {
                    "range": "147.161.228.0/23",
                    "vpn": "",
                    "gre": "",
                    "hostname": "",
                    "latitude": "52",
                    "longitude": "5"
                },
                {
                    "range": "165.225.240.0/23",
                    "vpn": "ams2-2-vpn.zscloud.net",
                    "gre": "165.225.240.42",
                    "hostname": "ams2-2.sme.zscloud.net",
                    "latitude": "52",
                    "longitude": "5"
                },
                {
                    "range": "147.161.172.0/23",
                    "vpn": "",
                    "gre": "165.225.240.42",
                    "hostname": "",
                    "latitude": "52",
                    "longitude": "5"
                },
                {
                    "range": "147.161.230.0/23",
                    "vpn": "",
                    "gre": "",
                    "hostname": "",
                    "latitude": "52",
                    "longitude": "5"
                },
                {
                    "range": "147.161.232.0/23",
                    "vpn": "",
                    "gre": "",
                    "hostname": "",
                    "latitude": "52",
                    "longitude": "5"
                },
                {
                    "range": "147.161.234.0/23",
                    "vpn": "",
                    "gre": "",
                    "hostname": "",
                    "latitude": "52",
                    "longitude": "5"
                },
                {
                    "range": "147.161.224.0/23",
                    "vpn": "",
                    "gre": "",
                    "hostname": "",
                    "latitude": "52",
                    "longitude": "5"
                },
                {
                    "range": "147.161.226.0/23",
                    "vpn": "",
                    "gre": "",
                    "hostname": "",
                    "latitude": "52",
                    "longitude": "5"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
'@
```

Now for the actual code:

```
# Convert json to an object
$data = $json |ConvertFrom-Json

# Iterate over each property (cloud provider?) on the root object
foreach($provider in $data.psobject.Properties){
  # save the provider name for later
  $providerName = $provider.Name
  # Iterate over each property (geographic region?) on the provider object
  foreach($region in $provider.Value.psobject.Properties){
    # save the region name for later, remove the `continent : ` prefix
    $regionName = $region.Name -replace '^.*?:\s*'
    # Iterate over each property (datacenter location?) on the region object
    foreach($location in $region.Value.psobject.Properties){
      # save the location name for later, remove the `city : ` prefix
      $locationName = $location.Name -replace '^.*?:\s*'

      # Extract the network information, attach the parent details
      $location.Value |Select-Object *,@{Name='provider';Expression={$providerName}},@{Name='region';Expression={$regionName}},@{Name='location';Expression={$locationName}},
    }
  }
}
```

For which you'll get output like this, much easier to work with:

```
range     : 147.161.174.0/23
vpn       :
gre       :
hostname  :
latitude  : 24.453884
longitude : 54.3773438
provider  : zscloud.net
region    : EMEA
location  : Abu Dhabi I

range     : 185.46.212.0/23
vpn       : amsterdam2-vpn.zscloud.net
gre       : 185.46.212.36
hostname  : ams2.sme.zscloud.net
latitude  : 52
longitude : 5
provider  : zscloud.net
region    : EMEA
location  : Amsterdam II

range     : 147.161.228.0/23
vpn       :
gre       :
hostname  :
latitude  : 52
longitude : 5
provider  : zscloud.net
region    : EMEA
location  : Amsterdam II

range     : 165.225.240.0/23
vpn       : ams2-2-vpn.zscloud.net
gre       : 165.225.240.42
hostname  : ams2-2.sme.zscloud.net
latitude  : 52
longitude : 5
provider  : zscloud.net
region    : EMEA
location  : Amsterdam II

range     : 147.161.172.0/23
vpn       :
gre       : 165.225.240.42
hostname  :
latitude  : 52
longitude : 5
provider  : zscloud.net
region    : EMEA
location  : Amsterdam II

range     : 147.161.230.0/23
vpn       :
gre       :
hostname  :
latitude  : 52
longitude : 5
provider  : zscloud.net
region    : EMEA
location  : Amsterdam II

range     : 147.161.232.0/23
vpn       :
gre       :
hostname  :
latitude  : 52
longitude : 5
provider  : zscloud.net
region    : EMEA
location  : Amsterdam II

range     : 147.161.234.0/23
vpn       :
gre       :
hostname  :
latitude  : 52
longitude : 5
provider  : zscloud.net
region    : EMEA
location  : Amsterdam II

range     : 147.161.224.0/23
vpn       :
gre       :
hostname  :
latitude  : 52
longitude : 5
provider  : zscloud.net
region    : EMEA
location  : Amsterdam II

range     : 147.161.226.0/23
vpn       :
gre       :
hostname  :
latitude  : 52
longitude : 5
provider  : zscloud.net
region    : EMEA
location  : Amsterdam II
```

Comment: @aster007 That's great. If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)